# Logstash Input MongoDB Error “No suitable driver found for jdbc:mongo://localhost:27017/test”

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash

logasth conf "input part"

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/home/jskang/mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mongodb.MongoClient"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongodb://localhost:27017/test"
    jdbc_user => ""
    statement => "db.noobject.find()"
  }
}
```

---

And Error print.

[ERROR][logstash.pipeline ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin. Plugin: "/home/jskang/mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar", jdbc_driver_class=>"com.mongodb.MongoClient", jdbc_connection_string=>"jdbc:mongodb://localhost:27017/test", statement=>"db.noobject.find()", id=>"df4ccfb18e5d04b6996063d547474649d5b7942a-1", enable_metric=>true, codec=>"plain_d07acd49-a189-4c04-b8bf-7bae6f423c49", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, jdbc_paging_enabled=>false, jdbc_page_size=>100000, jdbc_validate_connection=>false, jdbc_validation_timeout=>3600, jdbc_pool_timeout=>5, sql_log_level=>"info", connection_retry_attempts=>1, connection_retry_attempts_wait_time=>0.5, parameters=>{"sql_last_value"=>1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC}, last_run_metadata_path=>"/home/jskang/.logstash_jdbc_last_run", use_column_value=>false, tracking_column_type=>"numeric", clean_run=>false, record_last_run=>true, lowercase_column_names=>true> Error: Java::JavaSql::SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mongodb://localhost:27017/test

---

why do not logstash start!? i don't know... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same type of error then reinstalled the jdbc driver for mongo and configured like below,

```
 jdbc {
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongo://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017/database"
jdbc_user => "user"
jdbc_password => "password"
jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/logstash/mongodb-java-driver-3.4.2.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "com.mongodb.MongoClient"
statement => "SELECT * FROM table"
schedule => "*/30 * * * *"
tags => "mongodb"
```

}